# Generating public and private key pairs in c# and saving public key as plain text

Tags: encryption, private-key, public-key, plaintext, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I need to implement encryption between a C# application and a micro controller (pic32mx795). The issue I'm having is generating a public and private key pair I'm using RSACryptoServiceProvider, but I can only get the key attributes and not the complete public key.

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = RSA.ExportParameters(false);
```

I'm unable to supply the micro controller with the key parameters as it only takes the key (as bytes). There is a library that will be able to do this, but it will only be available sometime in November 2012 ([SW300055](http://www.microchipdirect.com/productsearch.aspx?Keywords=SW300055)). I am using the SW300052 library to perform encryption on the micro-controller (key size is limited to 256 bits).

I've also tried bouncycastle suggestion in this thread ([generating keys and showing them in a text box)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531054/generate-public-private-key-pair-and-show-them-in-textbox-in-asp-net). It saves the keys in a PEM format. From what I understand the keys are saved in a base64 format. I've specified the key length to be 256 bits but when converting the public key back to bytes, it is 62 bytes.

```
byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String (publicKeyString);
```

I've also looked at Microsoft's Strong Name tool (sn.exe), but the minimum key size it supports is 384 bits.

Is there any way that I can generate a public private key pair and get the public key in plain text/bytes using c# (or with any other tool)? Am I just better off using symmetric key encryption to encrypt a session key?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [certificate server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on a windows box and request them directly. You'll need to install MS certificate services.
You can also use [makecert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3.aspx) and access the key with [c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.publickey.aspx).

Or you could [generate the keypair programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e9ft273.aspx).